# PHP crypt() always failing?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, crypt

I'm quite new to encryption and passwords and so on, and I have some suspect code here that seems to be failing. I create a new user and insert their password into mysql. The password inserted is the output of

```
crypt( $user_input );
```

When I retrieve the row and run the following code to verify the user so they can log in, it returns false (and yes, the user IS inputting the correct password). This works on a Windows machine but not on Ubuntu - the user has been created on Ubuntu. Is there something that I am overlooking?

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {   
error_log("Before crypt");
if( crypt( $password, $row->password) == $row->password ) {
    error_log("Crypt works!" );
    return true;
} else {
    error_log("Crypt fails!");
    return false;
}
}
```

EDIT: 
I've done some logging, and here's what I get:

Ouput from crypt( $password ) is:
     $6$1ySEgqi5$X9t7CZ4FXjjUReCu2VQF0klBY5kWQkb8LlIIk9oQ4RD4.W.1/IWMZW7/XaqDXIv8owWSpmLmvI.kAFGSbxELZ1

The hash stored in MySQL is:

$6$/RYC6Gax$uNhUzQPDmJy29DgUB06Ilv4Oh69D5h7NfnBSW1

They clearly aren't the same. What's going on!?

Comment: Have you tried making sure $row->password contains what you think it does? try echoing the input, db and output values and comparing them manually

Comment: Ok, so I've done some logging in the edit above ^^^

Comment: here you should find the solution to your problem [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258860/php-crypt-returning-wrong-answer)

EDIT: Read the first comment (link)

Comment: The first comment suggests what I am already doing? Look at my code

Comment: Indeed it does show something that you are already doing, but what I meant to show you is that `crypt()` determines what algorithm is in use which might cause troubles.

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand how that might cause a problem, however. If crypt() is choosing the algorithm to use, surely it's choosing the same algorithm both times, so why should the outputs not match?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, although it took me a while to realize it. So for the benefit of anyone else who runs into this problem...check the size of the column storing the hash in your database!

The code was originally written on a Windows system, but when I ran it on a Linux system (Ubuntu) the crypt() function was then using the SHA-512 algorithm which needed a longer column length. I changed the column to CHAR(128) in MySQL and bingo, it worked!!!